# Parsing and converting non standart .ini files python

Tags: python, config, ini

I am parsing an .ini file with python

```py
import ini

def par():
    with open('file.ini', 'r') as f:
        contents = ini.parse(f.read())
    return contents
```

And when executing the code gives an error

```
File "file.py", line 40, in par
    contents = ini.parse(f.read())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ini\__init__.py", line 29, in parse        
    data[section][key] = value
KeyError: ''
```

It probably gives an error because of non standard stucture for an .ini file 
example of the file stucture:

```
[title]
a::b = 1
f::g = 12
```

Is there a way to parse and convert dicts to such non standart .ini files?

Comment: Are you aware of [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)? This is designed to handle parsing ini files and is a part of the standard library.

Comment: The example you give is not nonstandard; it's perfectly fine for most section-aware ini parsers. `::` is unusual, but as long as it's just treated as part of the key name, it doesn't change anything about how the parser needs to work.

Comment: I didnt try configparser

Comment: Please accept my answer if it has solved your problem. If it hasn't, please comment so that I can provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) and specify the key/value delimiters.

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser(delimiters=("=",))
config.read("file.ini")
print(config["title"]["a::b"])
print(config["title"]["f::g"])
```

```
1
12
```

`ConfigParser` uses `=` and `:` as delimiters [by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure). The `:` causes it to parse `a::b = 1` as `"a": ":b = 1"`. This is why you need to restrict the delimiters to `=` only.